# Busca binária com recursividade, mas aperece esse erro:"expected primary-expression before 'int'"

Tags: c, funções

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Funcao para busca binaria com recursividade
int BuscaBinariaR(int vetor[10], int inicio,int fim, int x) {

    int meio = (inicio+fim)/2;


    if(inicio>fim)

        return (-1);

    else if(vetor[meio]==x)

        return (meio);

    else if(vetor[meio]>x)

        return BuscaBinariaR(vetor,inicio,meio-1,x);

    else
        return BuscaBinariaR(vetor,meio+1,fim,x);

}


int main () {

//Criando um vetor para teste
    int vetor[10],i,x;  
    BuscaBinariaR(int vetor[10],0,9,int x);

//Preenchendo o vetor   
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
    printf(" Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
    }

    printf("Qual numero deseja buscar: ");
    scanf("%d",x);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando você vai chamar uma função você não pode declarar as variáveis ali como faz com os parâmetros. Faça:

```
BuscaBinariaR(vetor, 0, 9, x);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/BinarySearch.c).

Tem cara de ter outros problemas, mas este resolve assim. Por exemplo, essa chamada não parece estar no local correto.